# If else in blade templates depends on the role_id

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hi experts I'm trying to display here a content depending on logged in user. If their role id = 2, the link will be diplayed in the sidebar. But then it has an error. Thanks

```
@if(({{ Auth::user()->role_id }})=="2") 
            <li class="{{ Request::is('activity*') ? 'active open' : ''  }}">
                <a href="{{ route('profile.activity') }}" class ="{{ Request::is('activity*') ? 'active' : ''  }}"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> {{ Auth::user()->role_id }} User Log</a> 
            </li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@if((Auth::user()->role_id)=="2") 
   <li class="{{ Request::is('activity*') ? 'active open' : ''  }}">
       <a href="{{ route('profile.activity') }}" class ="{{ Request::is('activity*') ? 'active' : ''  }}"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> {{ Auth::user()->role_id }} User Log</a> 
   </li>
@endif
```

No need for the {{ }} as @ already means you are using php